# Does delete_by_query support query string?

Tags: elasticsearch

In older Elasticsearch version I simple do the following to delete data:

```
curl -XDELETE 127.0.0.1:9200/what/ever/_search?q=keyword
```

Now in Elasticsearch 6.X it's no longer supported. I had to use delete_by_query feature.

[According to the document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html), it seems like I can't use querystring there anymore, any ideas?

P.S

I need to match any fields, but the example query provided online matches a specific field, e.g

```
{
  "query": { 
    "match": {
      "message": "some message"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Val's answer is perfect, just note that the document that you have linked is using match query. check this page if you want to use query string: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Delete by Query API still supports a query in the query string, you just have to use `POST` instead of `DELETE` and the `_delete_by_query` endpoint:

```
curl -XPOST 127.0.0.1:9200/what/ever/_delete_by_query?q=keyword
```

Otherwise you can also you a `query_string` within the body, like this:

```
curl -XPOST 127.0.0.1:9200/what/ever/_delete_by_query -d '{
  "query": { 
    "query_string": {
      "query": "keyword"
    }
  }
}'
```

Comment: Are you trying to match the `message` field instead of all fields?